# CS:GO game state integration question

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm looking through the CS:GO game state information here -> https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Game_State_Integration

I haven't set anything up yet to analyse the data, but I'm curious about the returned values to the endpoint I will hypothetically set up, and if anyone has any further knowledge I'd really appreciate it.

Below is the list of "game state integrations" potential config settings:

```
"map_round_wins" "1"          // history of round wins
"map" "1"                     // mode, map, phase, team scores
"player_id" "1"               // steamid
"player_match_stats" "1"      // scoreboard info
"player_state" "1"            // armor, flashed, equip_value, health, etc.
"player_weapons" "1"          // list of player weapons and weapon state
"provider" "1"                // info about the game providing info 
"round" "1"                   // round phase and the winning team

// Below this line must be spectating or observing
"allgrenades" "1"             // grenade effecttime, lifetime, owner, position, type, velocity
"allplayers_id" "1"           // the steam id of each player
"allplayers_match_stats" "1"  // the scoreboard info for each player
"allplayers_position" "1"     // player_position but for each player
"allplayers_state" "1"        // the player_state for each player
"allplayers_weapons" "1"      // the player_weapons for each player
"bomb" "1"                    // location of the bomb, who's carrying it, dropped or not
"phase_countdowns" "1"        // time remaining in tenths of a second, which phase
"player_position" "1"         // forward direction, position for currently spectated player
```

What I'm wondering is what specific values are returned for each.  More specifically I'm looking at config settings `"allplayers_state" "1"` and `"allplayers_position" "1"`.  Does anyone know what specific values these are returning?   I'm hoping for x+y axis positions of crosshairs and longitude and latitude of position of player on map.

Does anyone know if these data are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, coordinates and viewing direction will be included. Note that these will only be returned to spectating clients (TV or spectator team).

Depending on what you've enabled your payload will include something like this:

```
"allplayers": {
        "1": {
            "name": "....",
            "observer_slot": 2,
            "team": "T",
            "state": { 
                // health, armor, flashed, etc
                ....
            },
            "match_stats": { 
                // scoreboard values (deaths, kills,...)
               ....
            },
            "weapons": { 
                // all weapons separated by slot and which one is active
               ....
            },
            "position": "-400.00, -150.00, -0.50",
            "forward": "-0.10, 1.00, -0.10"
        },
        "2": {
          ....
        },
```

As you'll probably know you enable or disable each of the sections separately.

```
"allplayers_state" "1"      
"allplayers_match_stats" "1"  
"allplayers_weapons" "1"      
"allplayers_position" "1"
```